# Getting sql error when using [Authorize(Roles = "Edit")]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I recently Implemented asp.net identity 2 into a MVC website. I followed this walkthrough here to change my pk to an INT [Here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity)

Every thing seems to work fine, I am able to assign users to roles as follows:

```
   var result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(), "Edit");
```

However the minute I use the Authorize attribute with a role specified on an action method such as:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Edit")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(UdlDownload model)
```

I get the following error:

```
The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 SQLExpress database file auto-creation error: 


The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory. The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because the provider determined that the database does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully check for existence of the application services database and automatically create the application services database:

1.If the application is running on either Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008R2, special configuration steps are necessary to enable automatic creation of the provider database. Additional information is available at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102. If the application's App_Data directory does not already exist, the web server account must have read and write access to the application's directory. This is necessary because the web server account will automatically create the App_Data directory if it does not already exist.
2.If the application's App_Data directory already exists, the web server account only requires read and write access to the application's App_Data directory. This is necessary because the web server account will attempt to verify that the Sql Server Express database already exists within the application's App_Data directory. Revoking read access on the App_Data directory from the web server account will prevent the provider from correctly determining if the Sql Server Express database already exists. This will cause an error when the provider attempts to create a duplicate of an already existing database. Write access is required because the web server account's credentials are used when creating the new database.
3.Sql Server Express must be installed on the machine.
4.The process identity for the web server account must have a local user profile. See the readme document for details on how to create a local user profile for both machine and domain accounts.   

Source Error:  

 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace:  


[SqlException (0x80131904): The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5341687
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +546
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1693
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +69
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +30
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +317
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +892
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +311
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +646
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +5356769
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +5358970
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +75

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.]
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +130
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) +89
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString) +27
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +386
```

Here is my StartUp.Auth

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(IdentityDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<FskUserManager>(FskUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<FskSignInManager>(FskSignInManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<FskRoleManager>(FskRoleManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<FskUserManager, FskUser, int>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) =>
                    user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                getUserIdCallback: (id) => (id.GetUserId<int>()))

                    //OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<FskUserManager, FskUser,int>(
                    //    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    //    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
 }
```

What Is causing my issue? I feel like i have left out an important step where I tell the asp.net framework to use my RoleStore and not its default one?

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="IdentityDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FSK_FskNetworks;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=p@ssword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

After adding `<clear/>` above my connection string.

```
Configuration Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

Source Error: 



Line 236:       <membership>
Line 237:           <providers>
Line 238:               <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
Line 239:           </providers>
Line 240:       </membership>


 Source File:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line:  238
```

Comment: Does it work if you add a `<clear/>` line above the connection string?

Comment: After adding `<clear/>` I am not receiving a different error. I will added to my question.

Comment: its not in my web.config ... if you look at the error message its referencing the machine.config for some odd reason?

Comment: Oh yes, then add another `<clear/>` to your `web.config` to remove the membership provider.

Comment: What has the clear got to do with my error? So I can try and understand what you think could be the issue? The connection string works with the rest of the Identity System?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `machine.config` file already contains certain values such as connection strings, membership provider and role manager setup and your `web.config` file inherits all settings from there.

The `machine.config` file on your machine is set up to add a membership provider using a connection string called `LocalSqlServer`. So when you use the `Authorize` attribute, it first tries to use that provider instead of `Identity`. The same goes for the role manager.

You can disable this by clearing the existing providers in your `web.config` like this:

```xml
<configuration>
    ....
    <system.web>
        ...
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager enabled="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Additionally you may need to add this to your `appSettings`:

```xml
<appSettings> 
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" /> 
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Under which section am I meant to add the membership? ` <system.web>`

Comment: Is this normal? Why have I never seen any mention of the Machine.config effecting it in any tutorials? is this an odd case that is happening on my computer? Can I not just totally ignore the machine config? Can I not delete it?

Comment: It's pretty common. The machine config is required but can differ on machines. It likely depends which version of IIS is installed.

Comment: Now im getting another error in the machine config, `Line 246:  <roleManager>
Line 247:   <providers>
Line 248:    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
Line 249:    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
Line 250:   </providers>` Line 248

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75198/discussion-between-zapnologica-and-davidg).